# What does flatmap in apache beam exactly do to the input pcollection when returning to the caller?

Tags: python, apache-beam

I am using *apache beam 2.10* and trying to understand what exactly [flatmap](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.11.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html?highlight=flatmap#apache_beam.transforms.core.FlatMap) is doing when returning the pcollection to the caller.

Reading the explanation on online documentation, I thought *flatMap* simply splits the set of PCollection elements into single pcollection like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670930/apache-beam-flatmap-vs-map) example.

> The callable must return an iterable for each element of the input
>   PCollection. The elements of these iterables will be flattened into
>   the output PCollection.

But in case of below code , *flatMap* flattens every single character of "Hello World" instead of returning "Hello World" as a whole.

```
def simple(x):
    logging.info("Inside simple type: {0}, val: {1}".format(type(x), x))

    # Just return
    return x

def run():
    with beam.Pipeline(runner='DirectRunner') as p:
        elems = p | 'map:init' >> beam.Create(["Hello World"])

        #
        # Sample with FlatMap
        #
        ( elems | 'flatmap:exec'   >> beam.FlatMap(simple) # 1 to 1 relation with flatmap
            | 'flatmap:out'    >> beam.io.textio.WriteToText(file_path_prefix='flatmap')
        )

def main():
    run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

### RESULT

```
H
e
l
l
o

W
o
r
l
d
```

But when I return a *generator* the iterated result , like in this [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/data-science-on-gcp/blob/16f83a921b568bda5c9501273b440972159e6c9f/04_streaming/simulate/df05.py#L78), it seems to become as pcollection.

```
def simple(x):
    logging.info("Inside simple type: {0}, val: {1}".format(type(x), x))

    # Just return
    yield x

def run():
    with beam.Pipeline(runner='DirectRunner') as p:
        elems = p | 'map:init' >> beam.Create(["Hello World"])

        #
        # Sample with FlatMap
        #
        ( elems | 'flatmap:exec'   >> beam.FlatMap(simple) # 1 to 1 relation with flatmap
            | 'flatmap:out'    >> beam.io.textio.WriteToText(file_path_prefix='flatmap')
        )

def main():
    run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

### RESULT

```
Hello World
```

#### ADDED ON May 2, 2019 JST

If I literally return a *iterator* then a string is iterated and each character is flattened into PCollections.

```
def simple(x):
    logging.info("Inside simple type: {0}, val: {1}".format(type(x), x))

    # Just return
    return iter(x)

def run():
    with beam.Pipeline(runner='DirectRunner') as p:
        elems = p | 'map:init' >> beam.Create(["Hello World"])

        #
        # Sample with Map
        #
        ( elems | 'flatmap:exec'   >> beam.FlatMap(simple) # 1 to 1 relation with flatmap
            | 'flatmap:out'    >> beam.io.textio.WriteToText(file_path_prefix='flatmap')
        )

def main():
    run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

### RESULT

```
H
e
l
l
o

W
o
r
l
d
```

So what does flatMap exactly do when returning the PCollection to the caller function?

Answer (score 2):

`FlatMap` assumes that the return type of given function is `iterable`. In your first example, `simple` returns `"Hello World"`. As `iterable`, `"Hello World"` can be considered as `['H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d']`. Therefore, your first example works like following:

1. `[] -> create -> ["Hello World"]`
2. `["Hello World"] -> map -> [['H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d']]`
3. `[['H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d']] -> flatten -> ['H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d']`

Final PCollection: `['H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d']`

In your second example, however, `simple` yields `x`. You can think that `simple` returns `iterator` which contains a single element `x`. So your second example works like this:

1. `[] -> create -> ["Hello World"]`
2. `["Hello World"] -> map -> [["Hello World"]]`
3. `[["Hello World"]] -> flatten -> ["Hello World"]`

Final PCollection: `["Hello World"]`

To answer your last question:

`yield x` and `return iter(x)` are semantically different. The following example may help you to understand the context.

```
>>> list(iter("abc"))
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> def x(): yield "abc"
>>> list(x())
['abc']
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer. I agree with your first point but I dont think returning a *iterator* is right way to understand because if I literally return iterator by *iter()* then still each character of "Hello World" is flattened to PCollections.